# Redirect subdomains to different paths while using separate SSL certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, dns, vhosts

I have a website with several different subdomains, and want to have parts of the site with higher levels of security than others. Such as Admin areas. I know that you can create as many certificates as you want. The issue that I am having is that whatever subdomain is listed first, it's `DocumentRoot` is applied to all the other subdomains redirecting to `https://`. Here is my code in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
    # HTTP Configuration
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName account.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
          DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account"
    </VirtualHost>

    # SSL Configuration
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName account.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/account.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/account.key
        DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account"
    </VirtualHost>

    #Secure Admin Config
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secure.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Secure"
RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
          DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Secure"
    # Other directives here

    </VirtualHost>
    #SSL Config for Admin area

    # SSL Configuration
        <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName secure.example.com
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/secure.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/secure.key
            DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Secure"
        </VirtualHost>
```

For example, if I were to go to `secure.example.com` it's `DocumentRoot` would be `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account` instead of `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Secure`

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your config looks OK to me.  Does the browser/client you are using support the TLS *Server Name Indication* extension?  That is the only way a client will be able to access `secure.example.com` over TLS.

Comment: I am using Safari, and it still doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers?  Recent version of Firefox or Chromium?

Comment: Yes, I have and they don't work either